# Rooting HTC One M8 fails using KingRoot

Tags: rooting, htc

I am trying to Root my HTC M8. I have tried using KingRoot to get it rooted, but I lost root and couldn't get it to get rooted again. Do you have a better way of rooting the device?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! Your phone was rooted but there was no change in recovery. So, It would be told that **stock recovery** has some scripts that **sets all back.** I have been through it already.
So, I have solution which helps in permanent rooting.

It can be applied nearly all devices over the globe **-->**

1. Download a custom recovery and flash it.
      
    You can find its **tutorial and requirement** based on your **model** on some searches.
2. Now, find a **flashable zip** file of **SuperSu** and flash this one using recovery.

    This zip file can be found by just searching these highlighted keywords.

This process is permanent for rooting as there is no one to check system changes for SuperSu binary. And as recovery has already root access. So, it can share it with you. I hope it may be helpful for many people.